# Hiding components with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am starting out with React.js just now and I had a question about react router.  In particular I am a little confused about what it means to have nested routes in react router.  Suppose that I have the following code (taken from react-router's github page)

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    {/* Show the dashboard at / */}
    <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
      <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Then what happens when I go to the link `/inbox/messages/<id>` does the inbox component get hidden?  Which views hide when you go to a router link and which ones stay in sight?  Also how can you keep track of which components are hidden and which are not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inbox` component is the parent component

```
const Inbox = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <MessageList />
    { children }
  </div>
)

const Message = ({ content }) => (
  <div>
    { content }
  </div>
)
```

So you are always going to see the `MessageList` from any `inbox` route. Does that help?

Comment: Did you mean that if I am in `/inbox/messages/1` I will always see `inbox`?

Comment: Correct. `Message` gets passed as a property called `children` to `Inbox`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to get started with React!  I was having a hard time setting up the server and the dependencies so I asked here!

Comment: That is what we are here for. Let me know if you have any other questions. Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using `<Switch>` (which you can use by  wrapping around your `<Route>`s like a `<Div>`), react-router will display nested components *inclusively*. In other words, in your example, the message will be shown *inside of* the inbox, with both being displayed at the same time.

`<Switch>`, on the other hand, will make it so that only the first matching `<Route>` will be displayed, so only the inbox would be displayed in your example. That's one way of "hiding" elements you don't want to be visible.